# "Position in/at/for your company"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-in, in-for

Which is correct?

> - I am writing to apply for the position of ____ in your company.
> - I am writinng to apply for the position of ____ at your company.
> - I am writinng to apply for the position of ____ for your company.

Comment: Would depend on the position being applied for. For eg, a consultant works "for" a company not "at" or "in" a company but a deputy manager or programmer works "in" a company.

Comment: and a health care assistant, or a caregiver? Would that be '"for a company? so: I am writing to apply for the position/role of caregiver for your company:

Comment: In that case, it can be "at"...for the position of caregiver at your company

Comment: PS. Better to state the name of the company rather than saying, 'your company'.

Answer (score 12):

As part of my job as an project manager, I have written a few job descriptions and read quite a few inquires like the one you mention.  In my experience, when the phrase is "work --- your company", it is almost always "*at* your company".  Actually, it is usually phrased "*at* Acme Widgets" or whatever the company name is.

If the company pays you, you work for the company.  Most people would also work *at* the company.  An exception, as Mamta D says, is that consultants don't work *at* the company.  In American English, people don't work *in* a company--they work *in* a specific department such as accounting.  They also work *in* a specific building and *at* a specific location (street address).

Although people work *for* a company, the job is not *for* the company, it is *at* the company.  So, you could apply to be an accountant *for* Acme Widgets, apply to work *in* the accounting department at Acme Widgets or apply for the position of accountant *at* Acme Widgets.  The third form is what I most often see.

Comment: +1 on differentiating between "work" and "job". Hollywood movies tend to lump them together